# How to undo the command “wmic path Win32_Share delete”?

Tags: windows, network-shares, wmic

I ran this command in elevated cmd (win 10):

```
wmic path Win32_Share delete
```

I was trying to do something else. Now I can't map network drives. How can I undo the change?

Answer (score 0):

These are not regular changes so may be difficult to recover from.  Try the following:

**1. DISM / SFC**

> (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
>
> (2) DISM.exe /Online
> /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
>
> (3) DISM.exe /Online
> /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
>
> (4) SFC /SCANNOW
>
> (5) Restart when all
> the above is complete and test.

**2. Make a new, test, Windows User Profile** (Account). Log into the new account and test Mapping a Folder.  Your user profile may be damaged.

**3. Windows Repair Install** If the profile appears OK, and step 1 did not yield results, do a Windows 10 Repair Install

> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10
>
> Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. If the Repair will not run as per above, use
> the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key, then run
> Setup on the USB Key.
>
> This will launch the Repair and proceed normally. Use the option to
> Keep Everything.

**4. If all the above fails**, back up everything and reinstall Windows 10.